# Catalog price rule is not getting applied

Tags: magento2

I have set a catalog price rule for a specific product using Sku. I scheduled the rule, but when I check **`catalogrule_product & catalogrule_product_price`** table both are empty. Can someone guide me on how to debug this issue

Even when I check content staging dashboard it is showing Upcoming

[image]

According to AEST it is 17th date

Comment: please check catalogrule,catalogrule_customer_group,catalogrule_group_website,catalogrule_website data exist or not...

Comment: run indexing command

Comment: I already run indexing command

Comment: @AnasMansuri Not empty - catalogrule, catalogrule_customer_group,catalogrule_website
Empty - catalogrule_group_website

Comment: Make sure your server Time zone and Magento Time zone are same.

Comment: I am running in my local system. My system time zone is IST & magento is AEST